# Proof of Uniqueness for a particular system of ODES.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find for which values of $b>0$ the system:

\begin{align}
      f(x) = -b/2(g(x)^2)'-bg(x),\\
      g(x) = -b/2(f(x)^2)'-bf(x)
\end{align}

has a unique solution with $f(0)=g(0)=0$, where $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow [-1,\infty)$, and $-1 \leq f'(x),g'(x)$.

I already proved that for $b\leq 1$ the solution $f(x)=g(x)=0$ is unique. I wonder, if for $b>1$, there is a counterexample or a way to prove it.

Comment: is it really $-1\leq f'(x)$? or $0\leq f'(x)$?

Comment: It is −1≤f′(x). This came from a change of variables of a previous system: $f(x) = h(x)-x$ with $0\leq h'(x)$.

Comment: I see, is this a homework or a research problem?

Comment: It is research. I arrived at this system from an optimization problem.

Comment: Well, then you may want to verify if you can apply the Perron-frobenius theorem.